# Why does 物腰の低い mean “well behaving” and not the opposite?

Tags: expressions

If `物腰` means “(good) manners” and `低い` means “low, bad”, how is it possible that `物腰の低い` actually means “of good, gentle manners”?

I found this expression in an [article on *keigo*](https://docoic.com/3338#i-2) and was surprised that in one sentence, usage of an expression is considered “low in manners”, but at the same time “polite” and “making good impression”.

> 上司や取引先に対して、「よろしいでしょうか」を使うことで、物腰の低い丁寧な人物として良い印象を与えることができます。

My quick search [confirmed](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1151751121) the meaning  is opposite to I’d expect. But in no dictionary did I find `低い` meaning anything other than “low, bad quality, lower grade etc.”, with `最低` being an example of such meanings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The culprit there is `腰` meaning waist, but also attitude, power and willingness to act by oneself. It is a part of many expressions including “腰が低い” meaning “modest” and ”腰が高い” meaning “arrogant”.

The meaning then extends to `物腰` as an “attitude towards things” too. “物腰が低い” is then “having modest manners”.

Other interesting expressions with 腰 would be:

- 腰が重い slow in action
- 腰が軽い hasty
- 腰を上げる reluctant
- 腰を入れる resolute

Comment: The last two are verb phrases and should not be translated as adjectives.

Comment: @aguijonazo Well, Japanese adjectives are very verb-like and verbs can act as attributes, so hence the consistency. But you are right. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: I meant they don't mean what those adjectives mean because they refer to actions.

Comment: I guess aguijonazo's point is that 腰を上げる/腰を入れる does not mean _reluctant_ /_resolute_, but _start doing something reluctantly/resolutely_.